# C# WPF Pop is being drawn multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

All I have created a custom hex viewer tool for viewing a particular file type. 
As part of the requirements I need to highlight certain bit values once I hover over a hex range (which is implemented via C# Run class).

The problem is about 50% of the time I get multiple popups drawn on top of each other rather than one.

See below:
[image]

Here my relevant code snippet in C#:

```
private Popup popup = new Popup();

        void ToolTip_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO: base popup action on data value
            if (popup.IsOpen!=true)
            {
                if (sender is Run && HexDocumentUIHelperUtility.zftSequenceBitsMouseUp)
                {
                    Run runControl = sender as Run;
                    if (runControl != null)
                    {


                        //popup.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        //popup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

                        TextBox textBox = new TextBox(); 
                        textBox.Text = this.getZftBitsVisualization().getBinaryString();
                        int startHighlight = this.getZftBitsVisualization().getHighlightIndex();
                        int length = this.getZftBitsVisualization().getHighlightLength();
                        //textBox.SelectionStart = startHighlight;
                        //textBox.SelectionLength = length;
                        textBox.SelectionBrush = Brushes.Gold;
                        textBox.Select(startHighlight, length);
                        textBox.FontSize = 15; 
                        popup.Child = textBox;
                        //get the current mouse position 
                        //I adjusted the mouse Y coordinate by minus 20 pixels in order to avoid the popup vbeing displayed on top of the hex range
                        int mouseYCoordinate = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.Y + 20;
                        popup.HorizontalOffset = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.X;
                        popup.VerticalOffset = mouseYCoordinate;
                        popup.IsOpen = true;
                        textBox.Focus();

                    }
                }
            }//if the pop is not already opened 
        }

        void ToolTip_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Run)
            {
                Run runControl = sender as Run;
                if (runControl != null)
                {
                    if (popup != null)
                    {
                        popup.IsOpen = false;
                        popup.Child = null;


                    }
                    if (highlightedRunList != null)
                    {
                        highlightedRunList.Clear();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are testing if the popup is already open at the top of the method but not actually setting that it is until much further down.

This gives the mouse enter event chance to fire several times before finally setting `IsOpen` to true preventing further popups opening.

Move the setting of `IsOpen` to immediately after the test for the popup not being open. You can always set it back to false if the popup fails.

Comment: I was optimistic about answer but it didn't help, thanks anyways.